# sequential pipe in shell script

Tags: shell, pipe, mpi

I have a rather long `pipe`, with jobs executed using `mpirun` and after that copying files. Now, the `cp` is occurring before the `mpirun` is complete. I think the error is due to some thread might be finished, and overwritten by the next job(the `*.opt3` is properly copied, but not the `*.opt1` and `*.opt2`). How I can make the `cp` wait until the job is **really** finished?

```
mpirun -np $NPROCS --machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE vasp_std; cp INCAR INCAR.opt1; cp CONTCAR POSCAR.opt1; cp OUTCAR OUTCAR.opt1; mv CONTCAR POSCAR; sed -i 's/EDIFF = 1.00e-04/EDIFF = 1.00e-05/g' INCAR; mpirun -np $NPROCS --machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE vasp_std; cp INCAR INCAR.opt2; cp CONTCAR POSCAR.opt2; cp OUTCAR OUTCAR.opt2; mv CONTCAR POSCAR; sed -i 's/ISIF = 3/ISIF = 2/g' INCAR;mpirun -np $NPROCS --machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE vasp_std; cp INCAR INCAR.opt3; cp CONTCAR POSCAR.opt3; cp OUTCAR OUTCAR.opt3
```

N.B. The `vasp_std` is an executable and I don't have the source code.

Comment: Did you checked with `ps -ef | grep mpirun` that all previous `mpirun` instances are not running?

Comment: That will give me info about **all** mpi processes; which is not intended, as I may have multiple mpi from different sources.

Comment: what filesystem are you using ? what if you `mpirun -np $NPROCS --machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE md5sum INCAR; md5sum INCAR` before the first copy ? do all your node have the same version of the file ?

Comment: As written, there's no pipeline there.  There is just a long sequence of sequential commands.  Each semicolon shown marks the end of a command.  The `mpirun` command text ends at the semicolon before the first `cp`.  If `mpirun` exits before `vasp_std` exits, you've got problems.  You should replace each semicolon in that gruesomely long command line with a newline.  It will work the same.  Or you need to add some quotes around the command that `mpirun` is to execute.